# How does model.matrix select levels for interaction terms

Tags: r, model.matrix

`model.matrix` returns fewer levels if lower order terms are included with interaction terms. If two-factor variables have na and nb levels, respectively. In a complete model.matrix with interaction terms,

`model.matrix(~ A + B + A:B)`, shouldn't I have (na-1) + (nb-1) + (na*nb-1)?

In the following example, both `a` and `b` have three levels each. Together, they have nine levels.

```r
data(mtcars)
a <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
b <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
table (a,b)

   b
a    4  6  8
  3  1  2 12
  4  8  4  0
  5  2  1  2
```

For model matrix with only interaction term, It has all nine levels.

```
mod.I <- model.matrix(~ a:b)
colnames(mod.I)
[1] "(Intercept)" "a3:b4"       "a4:b4"       "a5:b4"       "a3:b6"      
[6] "a4:b6"       "a5:b6"       "a3:b8"       "a4:b8"       "a5:b8"
```

However, for model.matrix with only one lower order term, it drops levels from other variables too. In this case, b doesn't have term for b = 4.

```
mod.a <- model.matrix(~ a + a:b)
colnames(mod.a)
[1] "(Intercept)" "a4"          "a5"          "a3:b6"       "a4:b6"      
[6] "a5:b6"       "a3:b8"       "a4:b8"       "a5:b8"
```

This is equivalent to complete model.matrix.

```
mod.ab <- model.matrix(~ a + b + a:b)
colnames(mod.ab)
[1] "(Intercept)" "a4"          "a5"          "b6"          "b8"         
[6] "a4:b6"       "a5:b6"       "a4:b8"       "a5:b8"
```

I read it has to do with contrast, but, wouldn't contrast operate independently on interaction term? Also, If I want to know the coefficient of a4:b4 with resect to a3:b4, how would I do it?

Comment: I think this should be helpful - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147083/what-is-the-baseline-level-in-a-factor-by-factor-interaction

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. For `mod.a`, can the coefficient of `a4:b4` be calculated as `a4 + Intercept`, assuming Intercept has coefficient of `a3:b4`? How does one assign a significance level to this new coefficient if only one of the `a4` or `Intercept` is significant?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the output of model.matrix to see exactly what it has done  in any particular situation but in any case to calculate a full set of coefficients use `dummy.coef` like this or optionally use the `use.na=TRUE` argument.  See `?dummy.coef`

```
fm <- lm(mpg ~ a + a:b, mtcars)
dummy.coef(fm)
```

giving:

```
Full coefficients are 

(Intercept):       21.5                                                                
a:                    3       4       5                                                
                  0.000   5.425   6.700                                                
a:b:                3:4     4:4     5:4     3:6     4:6     5:6     3:8     4:8     5:8
                  0.000   0.000   0.000  -1.750  -7.175  -8.500  -6.450   0.000 -12.800
```